# Display an image from sdcard in NativeScript

Tags: android, xml, image, nativescript

I want to develop a simple app in NativeScript which displays an array of images that are stored in sdcard storage. I could access to these files using "file-system" module for NativeScript, but I couldn't display it.

I let you my code here

main-view-model.js

```
var fs = require("file-system");
var imageModule = require("ui/image");
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;
var imageSource = require("image-source");




var mediaFiles=[];
var cont=0;
var viewModel;
function createViewModel() {
    viewModel = new Observable();
    var sdcard = fs.path.join(android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath(), "Camera");
    var folder = fs.Folder.fromPath(sdcard);
    folder.getEntities()
    .then(function (entities) {
        // entities is array with the document's files and folders.
        entities.forEach(function (entity) {
            if (entity.extension==".png" || entity.extension==".jpg" ){
                mediaFiles.push(entity.path);
            }
        });
        //transicion();
    }, function (error) {
    });
}
function transicion() 
{ 
    //while (cont < mediaFiles.length){
    cont++;
    mostrarImagen(mediaFiles[cont]);
    //transicion() 

}
function mostrarImagen(ImagePath){
    console.log("muestro imagen "+ ImagePath);
    var img = imageSource.fromFile(ImagePath);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(img));
    viewModel.set("image", image);
    page.bindingContext = viewModel;

    //if (cont<mediaFiles.length-1)
  //  setTimeout("transicion()",2000);
}
exports.createViewModel = createViewModel;
```

main-page.xml

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo">
  <StackLayout>
    <Label text="Portaretratos" class="title"/>
       <Image src="{{ image }}" />
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `viewModel.set("image", image);` to `viewModel.set("image", ImagePath);`

Answer (score 0):

Use `img` instead of `image` in your `viewModel.set()`:

```
//You're creating 'img' here
var img = imageSource.fromFile(ImagePath);

//Logging 'img' here
console.log(JSON.stringify(img));

//And using 'image' here. (Use img instead)
viewModel.set("image", image);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function `mostrarImagen(ImagePath)`, do this:

```
var ImageModule = require("ui/image"); 
function mostrarImagen(ImagePath){
    var img = new ImageModule.Image();
    img.imageSource = imageSource.fromFile(ImagePath);
    viewModel.set("image", img.src);
    page.bindingContext = viewModel;
}
```

Hope this helps.